# Fast Computation of Eigenvectors of a Sparse Matrix

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, eigenvector

I am working on a project that involves the computation of the eigenvectors of a very large sparse matrix.
To be more specific I have a Matrix that is the laplacian of a big graph and I am interested in finding the eigenvector associated to the second smallest eigenvalue. 
Of course Matlab takes ages to compute the eigenvectors, even because it computes all of them. 
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much
Andrea

Comment: eigs return aigenvalues, not eigenvectors

Comment: `[V,D] = eigs(A)` returns both, just read the documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html

Comment: @natan " `[V,D] = eigs(A)` returns a diagonal matrix D of A's **SIX LARGEST** magnitude eigenvalues and a matrix V whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors."
it gets the largest, for the lowest it necessary to use `eigs(A,k,sigma)` but returns only eigenvalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this usage of `eigs`:

```
[v,c]=eigs(A,2,'sm');
```

for example:

```
A = delsq(numgrid('C',256));  
[v,c]=eigs(A,2,'sm');
```

generates a ~50K x 50K sparse matrix and find its 2 smallerst eigenvalues and eigenvectors in about 1 second in my old laptop...

Comment: Perfect it works! From the documentation I understood that was not possible

Comment: yea, sometimes one needs to read the documentation until the end :)